# SQLiteConstraintException error showing after start of every activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have this error popping out in logcat all the time. It always shows after every change of activity. And sometimes, the app disappears and in a second it shows again. There is not any fatal error in logcat, all I see is this:

```
2020-05-20 11:53:26.422 2940-8484/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=3324000 job_id=-1 period=6650000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201516000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1589968406417 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
    at aplm.a(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):76)
    at aplb.a(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):173)
    at aplb.a(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):21)
    at aplb.a(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):167)
    at aphk.run(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):8)
    at sob.b(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):12)
    at sob.run(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at sub.run(:com.google.android.gms@201516038@20.15.16 (120406-309763488):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

But it does not show anywhere to the code is there any solution to it?

Edit: Google libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

Comment: Maybe you are inserting data into the database,  on activity. And unique key constraint failed because you are adding same data.

Comment: This seems to be coming from GMS code. What are the versions of google library dependencies in your project?

Comment: @KrishnaSony The problem is I do not insert data into database anywhere in the app. I only use one prepopulated database, which I take data from, but I do not even use it in some activities where this error occur.

Comment: @laalto Added google libraries I use

Comment: pull db and check data in Db Browser for SQLite

Comment: @silentsudo And where do I get that database? I do not use in my app any.

Comment: FIrst consider updating those dependencies. You can find more recent version numbers in https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: In my case I use 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2' and it causes me the same error. If I delete this dependency from gradle - this error disappears. So the root of the problem is with Firebase I guess.

Comment: This might be of some use (i guess - it's been open for more than 1 year now).. 

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/361

Comment: I see this also when there is nothing related to using Room, but when dealing with analytics, but from the traces it is related to Google's gms

Comment: I don't think it's related to Firebase because it says SQLite in the log message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/361#issuecomment-664593540) opened in the `firebase-android-sdk` project:

> Since it requires an update to play services, I'm holding off from giving you a timeline for when this will roll out. But, this would require no action/SDK upgrades from developers and should get fixed on your customer devices automatically.

Comment: does it related to Google Service? It says SQLiteDatabase in the log.

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue. my case solved by adding firebase messaging artifactory to module gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
```

your case maybe fix by adding missing library.

Comment: I have the below API in gradle. still getting the issue


///firebase
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing" // App indexing
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics"

Answer (score 0):

I have incorrectly used the following in the "onMessageReceived" method

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = ContextCompat
                .getSystemService(this, NotificationManagerCompat.class);
```

And elsewhere I used the following

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = ContextCompat
                .getSystemService(this, NotificationManager.class);
```

By changing the first one like second one, and updating firebase and gsm modules

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')

// Play Services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.1"
```

the error went away. (I am not sure about `play-services-oss-licenses` that is related or not.)